# Expo Eas ios Build failed: Fastlane build failed with unknown error

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

Build failed: Fastlane build failed with unknown error. See logs for the “Run fastlane” and “Xcode Logs” phases for more information.

if anyone had this error before please let men know I am stuck in this for 2 days